# Can not set margin between header and picture

Tags: css, wordpress, margin, title

I am trying to increase the margin between each article title and article picture on my site. (wordpress)

I tried all variations of margin/padding - top/bottom in both the headers (h2) class and the picture's class... nothing works.

What could be the reason? Thanks for your help!

URL http://sparschweinkiller.de.w0127d50.kasserver.com/

index.php:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div id="post-area">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

     <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
   
            <div class="gridly-copy"><div><h2><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'afflink', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
         
                
                
                
                  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
       
             
            <?php    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'summary-image' ); // returns an array

?>
         
                 <div class="gridly-image">
                           
                <img class="wpimagehover alignnone wp-image-<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id() ?>" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="" width="300" height="250" data-fburl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-tweeturl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-pinurl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-stumbleuponurl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-sstyle="circle" data-sharetxt="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" data-animation="fade" /> 
                   
                </div>
                
                                
          <!-- <div class="gridly-category"><p><?php the_category(', ') ?></p></div>
            -->
    <?php } ?>
          
            <!-- POS TITLE -->
            
             <!--   <p class="gridly-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> 
            
</p>  -->


<div> <?php the_content('(Mehr lesen...)'); ?> </div>
      
   <!--Preis Anzeige  -->                 

  <div class="price">
      <p><?php echo '<div class="price">'. get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'preis', true).'</div>'; ?> </p></div>
                    

          
                    
   <!--Sparschwein killen button  -->                 
  <div class="sparbutton">              
 <p style="text-align: right;" >  
    <?php 
    $linkadress = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'afflink', true);

        echo do_shortcode( '[otw_shortcode_button href="' . $linkadress. '"             size="medium" icon_position="left" shape="radius" target="_blank"]Sparschwein Killen[/otw_shortcode_button]' ) ?> 

 </p>
</div>

                
                    
                    
        
                    
         </div>
       </div>
 
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    
<?php next_posts_link('<p class="view-older">View Older Entries</p>') ?>
    
 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS:

```css
/* colour styles : light  */
  body  { background: url(../images/light/bg.jpg) repeat #FFF;  font-size:12px; line-height:20px;  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;   }
  #wrap { width:94%; margin-left:3%;}
  
/* font styles */ 
  h1  { font-size:36px; line-height:41px; color:#000000; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:5px; }
  h2  { font-size:20px; line-height:23px; color:#000000; padding:0px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; margin-bottom: 10; }
  h3  { font-size:15px; line-height:25px; color:#858585; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-weight:normal;   }
  h4  { font-size:15px; line-height:25px; color:#000000; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-weight:normal; font-weight:bold;  } 
  h5  { font-size:13px; line-height:22px; color:#000000; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-weight:normal;  }
  h6  { font-size:12px; line-height:22px; color:#858585; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-weight:normal;  } 
  p   { font-size:12px; color:#454545; line-height:22px; margin:0px; padding:0px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; font-family:'Helvetica',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

/* list Styles */
  ul  { padding:0px; margin:0; margin-left:0px; font-family:'Helvetica',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:10px;   }
  ul li { font-size:12px; color:#858585; padding-left:10px; margin-bottom:7px; list-style:inside; list-style-type:square;}
  ol  { padding:0px; margin:0; margin-left:25px; font-family:'Helvetica',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:10px;   }
  ol li { font-size:12px; color:#858585; padding-left:10px; margin-bottom:7px;  list-style-type: decimal; }
  hr  { background:url(../images/hr.jpg) top center no-repeat; border:0; outline:0; clear:both; height:10px;}
 
/* link styles */ 
  a:link   {color:#444444; text-decoration: none;} 
  a:visited  {color:#444444; text-decoration: none;}
  a:hover   {color:#000000; text-decoration: none;}
  a:active   {color:#444444; text-decoration: none;}
  a:focus   {outline-style: none;}   
 
/* header nav styles */ 
  #header     { width:100% }
  #logo     { margin-top:35px; margin-bottom:15px; }
  #nav      { width:100%; background:url(../images/light/bg-row.png) top left repeat-x; height:57px; overflow:hidden;   }
  #nav ul     { display: inline; list-style: none;  margin:0px; padding:0px; height:42px; line-height:42px; clear:both;   }
  #nav ul li    { float: left;  display: inline;  font-size: 12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;   }
  #nav ul li a    { display:block; height:42px; margin-right:20px; text-decoration:none; margin-top:10px;  }
  #nav ul li a:hover { }
   
/* footer styles */
  #footer-area      { width:100%; display:inline; float:left; padding-top:10px; margin-top:20px; clear:both; background:url(../images/light/bg-row.png) top left  repeat-x; }
  #footer-area .widget    { width:310px; margin-right:10px; padding-top:15px; display:inline; float:left; font-size:12px; color:#454545; line-height:18px; font-family:'Helvetica',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  }
  #footer-area .widget h3   { color:#858585;}
  #footer-area .widget p     { color:#000;}
  #footer-area .widget ul    { margin-left:0px;}
  #footer-area .widget li    { color:#858585; }
  #footer-area .widget a   { color:#444444;}
  #footer-area .widget a:hover  { color:#000;}
  #footer-area .widget-copy  { width:280px; overflow:hidden; display:inline; float:left; margin-left:10px;} 

/* copyright styles */ 
  #copyright { clear:both; width:100%; background:url(../images/light/bg-row.png) top left repeat-x; display:inline; float:left; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; }
  #copyright p { padding-top:15px; color:#4f5356; font-size:12px; }
  #copyright a  {color:#858585; text-decoration: none;} 
  #copyright a:hover  {color:#000000; text-decoration: underline;}
 
 
/* post and page styles */ 
  .type-post     { width:770px; background:#FFF; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb; margin-right:10px; margin-top:15px; display:inline; float:left; position:relative;  }
  .type-page     { width:770px; background:#FFF; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb; margin-right:10px; margin-top:15px; display:inline; float:left; }
  .type-attachment    { width:770px; background:#FFF; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb; margin-right:10px; margin-top:15px; display:inline; float:left; }
  .gridly-image    { margin-top:10; }
  .gridly-category    { position:absolute; width:auto; background:#000; margin-top:-35px; z-index:10;  height:30px; overflow:hidden; left:0;}
  .gridly-category p   { margin:0; padding:0; line-height:30px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:40px; color:#fff; font-style:italic;   }
  .gridly-category a   { color:#fff; font-style:italic;}
  .gridly-category a:hover  { color:#555;}
  .gridly-copy     { width:710px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; overflow:hidden }
  .gridly-date     { width:150px;  color:#8e8e8e; font-size:11px;}
  .size-full     { width:100%; height:inherit;}
 .price            { font-size:24px; color:#8e8e8e;  }
  .sparbutton               {  position:absolute; z-index:1; }



/* post index styles */ 
  #post-area .post     { width:320px; background:#FFF; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb; margin-right:10px; margin-top:15px; position:relative;  }
  #post-area .post .gridly-copy   { width:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-top:10px; paddingbottom:20px; overflow:hidden; clear:both;}
  #post-area .post .gridly-date   { width:150px;  color:#8e8e8e; font-size:11px;  border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc; padding-bottom:0; padding-top:0; }
  #post-area .post .gridly-link   { width:150px; border-top:1px dotted #e8e8e8; color:#494e51;}

/* single post nav styles */ 
  .post-nav    { width:35px; display:inline; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:15px; }
  .post-next a    { background:url(../images/btn-left.png) top left no-repeat; height:35px; width:35px; display:inline; float:left; text-indent:-9999px; }
  .post-next a:hover { background:url(../images/btn-left.png) top right no-repeat; height:35px; width:35px;}
  .post-prev a    { background:url(../images/btn-right.png) top left no-repeat; height:35px; width:35px; display:inline; float:left; clear:both; text-indent:-9999px;}
  .post-prev a:hover { background:url(../images/btn-right.png) top right no-repeat; height:35px; width:35px;}

/* comment styles */
  .comments-area ol { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;  border-bottom:1px solid #8e8e8e; }
  .comments-area li { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; border-top:1px solid #8e8e8e; width:100%; clear:both; display:inline; float:left; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;  } 
  .avatar    { display:none;} 
  .reply    { display:none;}
  .comment-meta   { display:none;}
  .comment-author  { font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; }
  #comment-form  { width:50%; }
  .text-input   { clear:both; border:1px solid #8e8e8e; margin-bottom:5px; width:90%; padding:7px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#555; font-size:12px;  }
  .comment-input   { clear:both; border:1px solid #8e8e8e; margin-bottom:5px; width:90%; padding:7px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#555; font-size:12px;  } 
  .comment-submit  { clear:both; width:120px; height:30px; line-height:25px; background:#e5e5e5; border:1px solid #8e8e8e;   }

/* Additional and WordPress styles */
  .clear    { clear:both;}
  .aligncenter   { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
  .alignleft  { float: left; margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:10px; }
  .alignright  { float: right; margin: 0 0 20px 20px; }
  .wp-caption  {  text-align: left; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; }
  .wp-caption-text  { margin-top:2px;  text-align:left; font-style:italic;  font-size:11px; color:#999; } 
  .sticky      {}
  .gallery-caption  {} 
  .bypostauthor   {}
  blockquote   { font-size:2em; line-height:23px; color:#000; margin-left:20px; border-left: 1px dotted #999; padding-left:25px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px; }
/* end of css file */
```

Comment: We can't diagnose PHP...we need to see the output HTML.

Comment: @user2039379, it is normally nice to say thanks to the users who have helped and mark an answer as correct if the answer helped, so other users who have the same problem as you will know how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your style is

```
.gridly-image {
margin-top: 10;
}
```

you are missing `px` after the 10. It should be

```
.gridly-image {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

You need to specify the px or else the browser won't know if you want it to be `10px`, `10%` or `10em`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out you `px` in your style please replace the following style with your `.gridly-image`

```
.gridly-image {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use margin-bottom on the h2 style, it's the same operation for the padding.

```
h2 {
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 23px;
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

}